# How to add source-map-loader in vue.config.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js

vue.config.js drives me nuts!!!

However since hours I try to add source-map-loader to vue.config.js...

This is my approach:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.module
            .rule('source-map-loader')
            .test(/\.(js|map)$/)
            .use('source-map-loader')
            .loader('source-map-loader')
            .enforce('pre')
            .end()
    },
}
```

vue inspect --rules gives me the default rules but ignores my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
config.module
    .rule("source-map-loader")
    .test(/\.js$/)
    .enforce("pre")
    .use("source-map-loader")
    .loader("source-map-loader")
    .end();
```

Your `enforce` call is not in the right place. Also, you just need to test for `.js` files, [as stated in the docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader#example-webpack-config).